# Having issues deploying node api to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to build a node api to heroku. When i run it locally, the initial route will display `Hello, we are deployed`, the `/wedding` . route will display the users in the wedding from the psql database, and this is all works locally displaying json data to the screen. Locally there are no errors, so i pushed everything to git, made the heroku app, and pushed everything to heroku. Heroku builds the app successfully and then when i open the app, it displays this screen

[image]

this is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

//middleware 
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('public'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello we are deployed');
});

const weddingRoutes = require('./routes/weddingRoutes');
app.use('/wedding', weddingRoutes);
```

this is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "just_us_api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.3",
    "npm": " 5.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js",
    "debugger": "DEBUG=*:* npm run dev"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/jdiperi88/just_us_api.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "html-entities": "^1.2.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "method-override": "^2.3.10",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg-promise": "^6.10.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: You've got a runtime error. Please run `heroku logs`, [edit] this question, and add the output from that command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can see the log details from the dashboard of Heroku, it is the easiest way to see your error.
Maybe you have some problems in the file inside '/routes/weddingRoutes'